# open files at last-edited position

Tags: find-file, history

What I want to achieve is this. I open a bunch of files, edit them and quit Emacs. then tomorrow I open one the files and I want Emacs to jump to the last edited position on that file.
How can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The built-in library `saveplace.el` contains a commentary that states:

```
;; Automatically save place in files, so that visiting them later
;; (even during a different Emacs session) automatically moves point
;; to the saved position, when the file is first found.  Uses the
;; value of buffer-local variable save-place to determine whether to
;; save position or not.
```

In recent versions of Emacs, the minor-mode `save-place-mode` is auto-loaded.  Thus, all that is needed is the following one-liner in the `.emacs` / `init.el` file:

```
(save-place-mode 1)
```

For additional information, see the emacswiki page:

https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/SavePlace